# Rebind an stateless ejb

Tags: java, unit-testing, ejb

The stateless bean works fine when deployed to app server,

```
@Stateless(name = "UtilitiesPersonClient")
@Loggable
public class UtilitiesPersonClient {
```

And the output of log shows created correctly :

```
java:global/my-app/UtilitiesPersonClient
java:app/my-app/UtilitiesPersonClient
java:module/UtilitiesPersonClient
```

However in my tests when I try to rebind this bean to a mock, it just doesn't get rebound and no error is thrown :

```
ejbContainer = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(p);

@Override
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    UtilitiesPersonClient mockService = mock(UtilitiesPersonClient.class);
    when(mockService.getMyMap(anyCollection())).thenReturn(mockedMap());
    ejbContainer
            .getContext()
            .rebind("java:module/UtilitiesPersonClient", mockService);
}
```

How do I rebind a stateless bean using ejbcontainer ?

Answer (score 0):

The rebind doesn't actually alter existing instances.  It only alters binding that is yet to occur.

So, to overcome this I simply injected the calling class, and altered the calling class to have a setter. I then used the setter to directly alter the instance.

```
@EJB
private MyService myService;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    UtilitiesPersonClient mockService = mock(UtilitiesPersonClient.class);
    when(mockService.getMyMap(anyCollection())).thenReturn(mockedMap());
    myService.setUtilitiesPersonClient(mockService);
}
```